# "msal" IdentityContextData for Django

Tags: python, django, azure-ad-msal

I am working with MSAL for the django project that i am developing with.
I Looked at the methods under class IdentityContextData(object) in context.py.

I See that there is a variable self._id_token_claims = {} under the clear method.
I have data coming in that variable. I saw a flask app that returns this variable as id_token_claims.

Could someone add a property for id_token_claims similar to username or token_cache

```
`
    @property
    def username(self) -> str:
       return self._username
`

`
    @username.setter
    def username(self, value: str) -> None:
      self._username = value
      self.has_changed = True
`
```

The above is the code snipet from class IdentityContextData(object) inside context.py.
I need to get user email that is returned in _id_token_claims.

But when i check the request in django, under request.identity_context_data, i can access request.identity_context_data._id_token_claims but i get the accessing protected property warning.

I see data like prefered_username and email in this _id_token_claims but i also get a warning for the same.

would appreciate someone adding the method to access this property directly like username or token_cache

Comment: Sorry, the package i use is ms-identity-web from ms-identity-python-utilities from . https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-samples-common. Anyone knows how to add on this package?